# OMNET++: Run simulation in command line

Tags: omnet++, veins

In my omnetpp.ini file, I have these lines describing cmdenv:

```
[General]
cmdenv-express-mode = false
cmdenv-output-file = log.txt
cmdenv-autoflush = true
cmdenv-status-frequency = 10000000s
```

So my outputs are redirected to a log file. To run my simulation I access to run -> run configurations -> user interface command line

Now, I need to run the omnetpp.ini file using a server so I need to run the .ini file in command line and not using the previous steps mentioned. I followed these two solutions that I found in the mailing list but they do not work:

1)  ./run -u Cmdenv -f omnetpp.ini

2)  opp_run  -u Cmdenv -f omnetpp.ini

This is what display:

```
HP-ProBook-650-G2:~/WorkspaceThese/Veins-4a2/examples/veins$ opp_run -u     Cmdenv -f omnetpp.ini 
OMNeT++ Discrete Event Simulation  (C) 1992-2014 Andras Varga, OpenSim     Ltd.
Version: 4.6, build: 141202-f785492, edition: Academic Public License --     NOT FOR COMMERCIAL USE
See the license for distribution terms and warranty disclaimer
Setting up Cmdenv...
Cmdenv: redirecting output to file `/home/yosra/WorkspaceThese/Veins-        4a2/examples/veins/log.txt'...

End.
```

Can someone help me to fix this issue please?

Comment: I do not understand your problem, can you edit your question again?

Comment: I need to run the omnetpp.ini file using the linux terminal and not the interface of Omnet++. I tried the two commands but they don't work.

Comment: What do you mean by "they do not work"? What does the error message display? Did you compile the code beforehand? Usually you also need to specify a config which should be executed '-c <config>'.

Comment: The returned message is:  HP-ProBook-650-G2:~/WorkspaceThese/Veins-4a2/examples/veins$ opp_run -u Cmdenv -f omnetpp.ini 
OMNeT++ Discrete Event Simulation  (C) 1992-2014 Andras Varga, OpenSim Ltd.
Version: 4.6, build: 141202-f785492, edition: Academic Public License -- NOT FOR COMMERCIAL USE
See the license for distribution terms and warranty disclaimer
Setting up Cmdenv...
Cmdenv: redirecting output to file `/home/yosra/WorkspaceThese/Veins-4a2/examples/veins/log.txt'...

End.
Can you pleasse tell me the full command that I should type in the terminal?

Comment: Can you update your question and put this message and the content of the log file which is mentioned there as well?

Comment: I edited the question, I am waiting your response.

Comment: Okay, so try using the script which is provided by Veins `./run -u Cmdenv -f omnetpp.ini -c debug` in case you are using the Veins demo scenario and let us know what happens.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I tried your command but il displays me the same message.

Comment: Okay, same questions again: Did you compile the code beforehand? What is written in the log file?

Comment: I build the project and everything was ok. I did not understand well how can I compile my code and which log file you mean please?

Comment: I meant the log file which you specified in the ini and which is referenced in the error message 'log.txt'. I suspect that the real error message is hidden in there.

Comment: My log file contaons all messages generated by omnet during the simulation, it is my output file, the minimum size of this file is 3Gb. I need to run the simulation using a command in the terminal that generates also the same log file.

Comment: Instead to open the interface of omnet to click manually the button run => command line; I need to it using directly the terminal without open the interface.

Comment: @Joe are you executing the command from within the example directory? Can you try specifying the run number using `-r <number>`. Try `-r 0`, for example... Comment out all the cmd related specifications in your config ini and try.

Comment: I tried -r 0; it displays me this error:  Error: NED type `RSUExampleScenario' could not be fully resolved, due to a missing base type or interface.  So I edited the ned path in omnetpp.ini file like this: ned-path = /home/Workspace/Veins-4a2/examples/veins/RSUExampleScenario but it displays another error:  Error: Error loading NED sources from `/home/Workspace/Veins-4a2/examples/veins/RSUExampleScenario': cannot temporarily change to directory `/home/Workspace/Veins-4a2/examples/veins/RSUExampleScenario' (does it exist?).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are able to run your simulation in `Cmdenv` mode from `Eclipse`, you may see what `Eclipse` uses to run the simulation. To do it add the Console ( `Window` | `Show View` | `Other` | `Console`) and start your simulation in `Cmdenv` mode. In the console you will see something like this:

```
Starting...

$ cd /opt/omnetpp/omnetpp-4.6/samples/tictoc/simulations
$ ../src/tictoc -r 0 -u Cmdenv -c General -n ../src;. omnetpp.ini

OMNeT++ Discrete Event Simulation  (C) 1992-2014 Andras Varga, OpenSim Ltd.
...
```

Here are the commands you are looking for.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, this is what I did before using the interface of OMNET++ IDE. What I need is to run the simulation without access to the IDE , i.e without open the interface of omnet++. I need a command that I can type in a terminal and it starts the simulation. Is there a command that do what I do please?

Comment: The commands you are looking for are in Console in Eclipse. Just write it down and close Eclipse. Then open a terminal and type these commands.

Comment: Thank you for your fast reply, I did not understand well your response. Should I install Eclipse to run the simulation in omnet? Can you please explain me more.

Comment: Eclipse is the GUI of OMNeT++, you call it "interface of OMNeT++".

Comment: I wasn't able to see these commands, probably because im using a more recent version of OMNeT++. I did however find out that building the project after changing a configuration option helped