# How to install and use valgrind in Omnet++ IDE for memory leak detection

Tags: valgrind, omnet++

I have faced the problem of not freeing the memory when using my simulation because after running the simulation once or twice, the simulation hangs and the operating system needs to be restart. I want to check the entire code with the Valgrind tool or a similar tool in the Omnet++ version 6 environment to detect memory leak. The OS is Ubuntu version 22.

Comment: What have you tried? Use `valgrind {your exe} {your exe arguments}`. It will be slow and use a lot of memory.

Comment: What OS do you use?

Comment: I use the Ubuntu version 22 operating system and the Omnet++ version 6 network simulater.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24935217/how-to-install-valgrind-properly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. To install Valgrind in Ubuntu use `sudo apt-get install valgrind`.
2. Determine the commands used to start your simulation, for example [that way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43710733/4653172).
3. In console run your simulation under Memcheck in Valgrind using recognized commands, for example:

   ```
   $ cd /home/user/omnetpp-6.0.1/samples/tictoc/simulations
   $ valgrind --leak-check=yes ../src/tictoc -r 0 -u Cmdenv -c General -n ../src;. omnetpp.ini
   ```

Comment: Dear Jerzy, is there another way else command line method such as GUI? Working with command style with many parameters isn't easy.

Comment: Eclipse used by OMNeT++ does not contain plugin for Valgrind. However, feel free to check method presented [here](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Linux_Tools_Project/Valgrind/User_Guide)

Comment: In thr command "valgrind --leak-check=yes ../src/tictoc -r 0 -u Cmdenv -c General -n ../src;. omnetpp.ini" :
what does mean each parameter? For example, 1) ../src/tictoc 2) -r 3) 0 4) -u 5) -c 6) General 7) -n 8) ../src 9) omnetpp.ini

Comment: `../src/tictoc` is relative path to the executable file of the simulation, `-r` selects run to start, `-u` determines the type of interface, `-c General` selects the section from `omnetpp.ini`, `-n` specifies path for NED files, `omnetpp.ini` is the name of configuration file. Parameters of command line are described in [OMNeT++ Simulation Library - Chapter 11](https://doc.omnetpp.org/omnetpp/manual/#cha:run-sim). BTW: you don't have to manually set parameters of command line. Instead you should recognize your complete command line (as described in point 2 of my answer) and just paste it.

Comment: In fact OMNeT++ DOES bundle the Linux Tools Project, so you can start your project in profile mode from the IDE, too.